# jQuery detects a focused input as non-focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a search icon before my input and because `input` doesn't have a `::before`, I've opted to have the following markup:

```
<div id="demos-search-bar" class="col-md-12">
        <svg version="1.1" id="demos-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
            .st0{fill:#3F3F3F;}
        </style>
        <path class="st0" d="M8,1c3.31,0,6,2.69,6,6c0,1.55-0.59,2.96-1.56,4.03l2.27,2.27c0.39,0.39,0.39,1.02,0,1.41
            C14.51,14.9,14.26,15,14,15s-0.51-0.1-0.71-0.29l-2.43-2.43C10.01,12.74,9.04,13,8,13c-3.31,0-6-2.69-6-6S4.69,1,8,1z M8,11
            c2.21,0,4-1.79,4-4c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S4,4.79,4,7C4,9.21,5.79,11,8,11z"/>
        </svg>
        <input type="text" id="demos-search" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

And because of this, I'm forced to use JS so that when the user clicks inside the wrapper `demos-search-bar` (maybe even on the icon itself), I can focus the actual input itself.

Problem is...it kinda...doesn't work. When I click anywhere outside the input itself (but not actually outside of the whole thing, on the body for example), it de-focuses for a second and then re-focuses properly, creating buggy behavior:

```js
let demosSearch = $('#demos-search');

$('#demos-search-bar').on('click', () => {
  const demosSearchInput = $('#demos-search');

  if (demosSearchInput.is(':focus')) {} else {
    demosSearchInput.focus();
  }
});

demosSearch.focusin((focusEvent) => {
  $('#demos-search-bar').addClass('searching');
});

demosSearch.focusout((blurEvent) => {
  $('#demos-search-bar').removeClass('searching');
});
```

```css
#demos-search-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#demos-search {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#demos-search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease, padding 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#demos-search-bar:hover {
  cursor: text;
}

#demos-search-bar.searching {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 12px 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demos-search-bar" class="col-md-12">
  <svg version="1.1" id="demos-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{fill:#3F3F3F;}
            </style>
            <path class="st0" d="M8,1c3.31,0,6,2.69,6,6c0,1.55-0.59,2.96-1.56,4.03l2.27,2.27c0.39,0.39,0.39,1.02,0,1.41
                C14.51,14.9,14.26,15,14,15s-0.51-0.1-0.71-0.29l-2.43-2.43C10.01,12.74,9.04,13,8,13c-3.31,0-6-2.69-6-6S4.69,1,8,1z M8,11
                c2.21,0,4-1.79,4-4c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S4,4.79,4,7C4,9.21,5.79,11,8,11z"/>
            </svg>
  <input type="text" id="demos-search" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not use the input background to display your icon?  Or since you are apparently using bootstrap, use an input group with label?  Both of those make things very simple and require no javascript.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I'm not aware of any techniques where I can put any image inside an input and also `inputs` don't have `:before/:after`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the background image technique:

```css
input {
  background: url('https://api.iconify.design/oi-magnifying-glass.svg') no-repeat left center / contain;
  padding-left: 20px;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Searchin..." name="s" />
```

And since it appears you are already using bootstrap, here is that technique for version 3.3.7, but similar in 4.x using your SVG:

```css
#demos-search-icon {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <label class="input-group-addon" for="exampleInputAmount">
    <svg version="1.1" id="demos-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#3F3F3F;}
      </style>
      <path class="st0" d="M8,1c3.31,0,6,2.69,6,6c0,1.55-0.59,2.96-1.56,4.03l2.27,2.27c0.39,0.39,0.39,1.02,0,1.41
        C14.51,14.9,14.26,15,14,15s-0.51-0.1-0.71-0.29l-2.43-2.43C10.01,12.74,9.04,13,8,13c-3.31,0-6-2.69-6-6S4.69,1,8,1z M8,11
        c2.21,0,4-1.79,4-4c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S4,4.79,4,7C4,9.21,5.79,11,8,11z"/>
    </svg>      
  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Searchin...">
</div>
```

Or using the stock graphics in bootstrap 3.3.7 (https://www.glyphicons.com/):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <label class="input-group-addon" for="exampleInputAmount">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Searchin...">
</div>
```

Comment: Much cleaner, much better.